How to pass specific StreamProvider value to the widget in Flutter
This is my first Stream class, I have similar class where the interval is 10 seconds and it increment value by 5 called AnotherStream. How can I make sure to pass these to specific widgets in build?
class CounterStream {
  final _controller = StreamController<int>();
  int _counter = 0;

  CounterStream() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
      _controller.sink.add(_counter++);
    });
  }

  Stream<int> get stream => _controller.stream;

  void dispose() => _controller.close();
}

This is the first consumer similar to another following consumer, If only specifier is Consumer how will it know what stream to listen to?
  Consumer<int>(
      builder: (context, counter, _) {
        return Text(
          '$counter',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
        );
      },
    ),

Currently both Consumer are listening to AnotherStream & CounterStream is not being used. I have passed both Stream in the MultiProvider & I also tried with different types, StreamProvider &  works as expected but not of same data type. What am I doing wrong here?
